# Custom selector image with three status in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I need a custom selector inside a ListView item that is clickable three times.
First click show image 1, second click show image 2, third click show image 3, fourth click go back to show image 1 and so on.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the [level-list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html) drawable.

Create a level-list drawable in the `/res/drawable` folder with your images.

> ```
>   <level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>       <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/image_1" />
>       <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/image_2" />
>       <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/image_3" />
>      </level-list>
> ```

- Set this drawable as a background for your image view.

> ```
> <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/iv_selector"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>         android:src="@drawable/level_selector"
>         />
> ```

Add a click listener for the drawable and update the image level

```
public void onCLick(View view) {<br>
                   LevelListDrawable levelListDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();<br>
               int level = levelListDrawable.getLevel();
               level = level + 1;<br>
               level = level % 3;<br>
               imageView.setImageLevel(level);<br>
           }
```